# What are the different htop kill signals?

Tags: process, kill, htop

I have recently started using `htop`, and I have been needing to kill processes, but when pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> on the process, it has been giving me this list of options, I just chose the one which is selected by defaults, but I don't know what that actually does, although it seems to work:

[image: htop signal options]

So really my question is, what are these different options, and which is best to use to kill a process?

Comment: Related question on Unix.SE: [Why is the UNIX system call kill named 'kill'?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/185027/53467)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First try

```
SIGTERM      15       Term    Termination signal
```

if this doesn't work

```
SIGKILL       9       Term    Kill signal
```

---

From `man 7 signal`

```
First the signals described in the original POSIX.1-1990 standard.

Signal     Value     Action   Comment
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
SIGHUP        1       Term    Hangup detected on controlling terminal
                              or death of controlling process
SIGINT        2       Term    Interrupt from keyboard
SIGQUIT       3       Core    Quit from keyboard
SIGILL        4       Core    Illegal Instruction
SIGABRT       6       Core    Abort signal from abort(3)
SIGFPE        8       Core    Floating point exception
SIGKILL       9       Term    Kill signal
SIGSEGV      11       Core    Invalid memory reference
SIGPIPE      13       Term    Broken pipe: write to pipe with no
                              readers
SIGALRM      14       Term    Timer signal from alarm(2)
SIGTERM      15       Term    Termination signal
SIGUSR1   30,10,16    Term    User-defined signal 1
SIGUSR2   31,12,17    Term    User-defined signal 2
SIGCHLD   20,17,18    Ign     Child stopped or terminated
SIGCONT   19,18,25    Cont    Continue if stopped
SIGSTOP   17,19,23    Stop    Stop process
SIGTSTP   18,20,24    Stop    Stop typed at terminal
SIGTTIN   21,21,26    Stop    Terminal input for background process
SIGTTOU   22,22,27    Stop    Terminal output for background process

The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or
ignored.

Next the signals not in the POSIX.1-1990 standard but described in
SUSv2 and POSIX.1-2001.

Signal       Value     Action   Comment
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
SIGBUS      10,7,10     Core    Bus error (bad memory access)
SIGPOLL                 Term    Pollable event (Sys V).
                                Synonym for SIGIO
SIGPROF     27,27,29    Term    Profiling timer expired
SIGSYS      12,31,12    Core    Bad argument to routine (SVr4)
SIGTRAP        5        Core    Trace/breakpoint trap
SIGURG      16,23,21    Ign     Urgent condition on socket (4.2BSD)
SIGVTALRM   26,26,28    Term    Virtual alarm clock (4.2BSD)
SIGXCPU     24,24,30    Core    CPU time limit exceeded (4.2BSD)
SIGXFSZ     25,25,31    Core    File size limit exceeded (4.2BSD)
```

Comment: It can be preferrable to use `SIGINT`, which is similar to pressing Ctrl+C and still lets the program finish orderly. I use it when terminating optimization runs using Gurobi: It immediately stops the program but the best found solution is still written to file.

Answer (score 6):

Those are Process signals in general and not just related to `htop`, you can list all signals using the command

```
kill -l
```

For example<sub>[source](http://meinit.nl/the-3-most-important-kill-signals-on-the-linux-unix-command-line)</sub> :

> -1 or -HUP - This argument makes kill send the "Hang Up" signal to processes. This probably originates from the modem/dial-in era.
>   Processes have to be programmed to actually listen to this process and
>   do something with it. Most daemons are programmed to re-read their
>   configuration when they receive such a signal. Anyway; this is very
>   likely the safest kill signal there is, it should not obstruct
>   anything.
>
> -2 or -SIGINT - This is the same as starting some program and pressing CTRL+C during execution. Most programs will stop, you could lose data.
>
> -9 or -KILL - The kernel will let go of the process without informing the process of it. An unclean kill like this could result in data
>   loss. This is the "hardest", "roughest" and most unsafe kill signal
>   available, and should only be used to stop something that seems
>   unstoppable.
>
> -15 or -TERM - Tell the process to stop whatever it's doing, and end itself. When you don't specify any signal, this signal is used. It
>   should be fairly safe to perform, but better start with a "-1" or
>   "-HUP".

The list from `signal.h` file:

```
+--------------------+------------------+
 *  |  POSIX signal      |  default action  |
 *  +--------------------+------------------+
 *  |  SIGHUP            |  terminate   |
 *  |  SIGINT            |  terminate   |
 *  |  SIGQUIT           |  coredump    |
 *  |  SIGILL            |  coredump    |
 *  |  SIGTRAP           |  coredump    |
 *  |  SIGABRT/SIGIOT    |  coredump    |
 *  |  SIGBUS            |  coredump    |
 *  |  SIGFPE            |  coredump    |
 *  |  SIGKILL           |  terminate(+)    |
 *  |  SIGUSR1           |  terminate   |
 *  |  SIGSEGV           |  coredump    |
 *  |  SIGUSR2           |  terminate   |
 *  |  SIGPIPE           |  terminate   |
 *  |  SIGALRM           |  terminate   |
 *  |  SIGTERM           |  terminate   |
 *  |  SIGCHLD           |  ignore      |
 *  |  SIGCONT           |  ignore(*)   |
 *  |  SIGSTOP           |  stop(*)(+)      |
 *  |  SIGTSTP           |  stop(*)     |
 *  |  SIGTTIN           |  stop(*)     |
 *  |  SIGTTOU           |  stop(*)     |
 *  |  SIGURG            |  ignore      |
 *  |  SIGXCPU           |  coredump    |
 *  |  SIGXFSZ           |  coredump    |
 *  |  SIGVTALRM         |  terminate   |
 *  |  SIGPROF           |  terminate   |
 *  |  SIGPOLL/SIGIO     |  terminate   |
 *  |  SIGSYS/SIGUNUSED  |  coredump    |
 *  |  SIGSTKFLT         |  terminate   |
 *  |  SIGWINCH          |  ignore      |
 *  |  SIGPWR            |  terminate   |
 *  |  SIGRTMIN-SIGRTMAX |  terminate       |
 *  +--------------------+------------------+
 *  |  non-POSIX signal  |  default action  |
 *  +--------------------+------------------+
 *  |  SIGEMT            |  coredump    |
 *  +--------------------+------------------+
```

further read:

- `man signal` , `man 2 signal` , `man 7 signal` , `man kill`
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html
- http://lasr.cs.ucla.edu/vahab/resources/signals.html
- http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/all-about-linux-signals

Comment: From the list you have most of them look the same, so what are the deferences between the ones which seem to do the same thing?

Comment: Each trap signal by its way that's the difference but in result most do same. take a look on the references, plus the man page for full documentation, indeed you can write a book on each signal!